# Explain polymorphism in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

Given the statement

```
A m = new B();
```

and knowing that class B is a subclass of class A and A is a subclass of Object,
explain what happens when the statement is evaluated.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The compiler complains that you haven't added the `homework` tag to your question.

Comment: Is this homework, or are you just curious what happens?

Comment: Actually is a past exam paper and i'm not sure how to tackle it.

Comment: It is clearly a beginner's question, what difference does it really make if this is homework, or an interview question, or whatnot... That said, the question isn't very clear: "explain what happens when the statement is evaluated" - what happens when? Compilation? Runtime? What is "evaluated"?

Comment: @Mehrdad Ahaha, you made my day!

Comment: @Mehrdad: I thought that meta-tags were discouraged these days?

Comment: @Donal: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60422/is-homework-an-exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- A variable called `m` is created, of type `A`
- An object of type `B` is constructed
- The variable `m` is assigned a reference to the created object

You can refer to `m` as if it is of type `A` without a cast.  This means that you can call any methods that are defined in `A`; if they are overridden, `B`'s version of the method is called instead.  You cannot call any methods that are specific to `B`, however, unless you use a cast.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is that since B is a subclass of A, this evaluation can occur normally.

A pointer to a base class can point to a derived class just fine, since the derived class is an instance of the base class.

Let's expand the example a bit more:

```
 A m;
 B n = new B();
 m = n; // Valid statement
```

m = n is a valid statement because we can only assign an A object to m. The compiler sees that B derives from A, so it is in actuality an A object. If it were an unrelated type, the compiler would yell at you.

Comment: Yes, it is. I guess he wants the mechanism with which Java understands and casts the type B to A

Comment: Ok, I know that an object of the type of a subclass can be created using the type provided by the superclass, I was just thinking if there's something more into it(compiling details, etc)

Comment: @EOS: Not really. I added a bit more to my answer, but there's very little going on in this statement.

Answer (score 0):

`RTTI` is the word. Run-Time Type Identifications.
I recommend you "Thinking in Java" by Bruce Eckel